# jQuery Failure to retrieve database update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am currently using jQuery to retrieve a database update to a column called "followers_count". The problem is that the data is not being sent. I'm not sure if the issue is with the PHP or jQuery code, or both. Any help is appreciated.

In changes.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';
require_once 'class.channel.php';

$currNum = $_POST['currentNumber'];

$seqNum = query( "SELECT currval('followers_count')" );

if ($seqNum == $currNum){
    exit(0);
}

$newNum = query("SELECT FROM follow WHERE followers_count > ".$currNum);

while ( $change1 = fetch_result( $newNum ) ) {
    echo "<count1>".$change1."</count1>";
}

?>
```

And in index.php:

```
<div>
  <div id="follow_count"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.post("changes.php", 
        { currentNumber },
        function(dat){
            $(dat).find('count1').each( function() {
                $('#follow_count').append(""+$(this).text()+"");
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you return something like `<count1>` ?

Comment: You are echoing multiple times in a while loop. Echo your response as json instead. Also add some error handling to your post (and inspect your network tab)

Comment: try `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})`. It might be caching the response.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that you're returning something like

```
<count1>1</count1>
<count1>2</count1>
<count1>3</count1>
```

And then you're doing

```
$(dat).find('count1')
```

But `dat` doesn't have any descendant elements matching that, they are all at "root" level.

You could use filter

```
$(dat).filter('count1')
```

but why bother, all you have if `<count1>` elements anyway, so you can just do

```
$(dat).each( function() { ...
```

Of course, this all very wrong, as `<count1>` isn't valid anything, not XML and certainly not HTML.
What you should be doing is returning JSON instead

As an added bonus, you're wide open to SQL-injection, unless `query()` does something magical?